# CSS Overflow only by X inside relative block without static

Tags: html, css

how I can do `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: visible;` inside div with relative, and I can't use static position, I need use only relative.

Comment: Please add more details and some code to your question.

Comment: You can't. You can't use `hidden` in one direction and `visible` in the other. It just doesn't work.

Comment: add some more details on your question, and as @NiettheDarkAbsol says You cannot use different values for two directions, if you do it automatically set elements to `visible`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible according to the CSS Overflow Module.

According to MDN Web Docs:

> Setting one axis to visible (the default) while setting the other to a
> different value results in visible behaving as auto.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like that, if Overflow in CSS have to different values as `overflow-x: scroll` and `overflow-y: hidden` they are converted automatically to `overflow: auto`